# Typecheck a project that has typed holes

Tags: haskell, cabal, typed-holes

I often use typed holes to define functions for which I know the interface and intend to implement later. When I run `cabal build`, it stops after the first module it encounters with typed holes, hiding type errors that may exist in other modules.

Is there any way of typechecking a project, and only failing for typed holes after the entire project has been built and typechecked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@chi very politely told me to Read The Docs. There seems to be two ways of configuring typed holes:

- The default behaviour, which makes typed holes a compile-time error. This causes compilation to stop after the first module encountered with typed holes, hiding both type errors and typed holes in other modules.
- `-fdefer-typed-holes` which will issue a warning upon encountering a typed hole, and go on to compile the rest of the project. If no other errors are encountered, a binary is built, with the typed holes demoted to runtime errors. On the one hand, all holes show up in the compiler output, but on the other, it is less than ideal for these to allow the build to succeed.

There is, however, a slightly hacky combination of flags that gets (almost) the desired behaviour:

```
-fdefer-typed-holes -Werror=typed-holes
```

This typechecks each module in the project, stopping for any (non-hole) type errors. If there are none in a given module, build prints out all the typed holes in the project and goes on to typecheck the rest of the project. Build only succeeds if it encounters no type errors or typed holes.

It would be even nicer if we could get type errors *and* typed holes in the same output, but you can't have everything.

Answer (score 3):

This excerpt from the [docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/typed_holes.html?highlight=typed%20holes) says it all.

> A “Found hole” error usually terminates compilation, like any other type error. After all, you have omitted some code from your program.
> Nevertheless, you can run and test a piece of code containing holes,
> by using the `-fdefer-typed-holes` flag. This flag defers errors
> produced by typed holes until runtime, and converts them into
> compile-time warnings. These warnings can in turn be suppressed
> entirely by `-Wno-typed-holes`.

Comment: It would be nice if these could stay compile-time errors, but it seems this is the best we'll get.

Comment: @AriFordsham A "compile-time error that doesn't halt the build" is a warning; that's exactly what you get with `-fdefer-typed-holes`. Only if you that **and** explicitly disable the warning with `-Wno-typed-holes` will typed holes become purely a runtime error.